# SunOS 5.10 - ignore certain files in ls

Tags: solaris, ls

I don't know why but I can't execute ls with ignore flag:

```
-bash-3.2$ ls -I '*.log'
ls: illegal option -- I
```

Do you know what else can I try?

Answer (score 1):

`-I` is a flag specific to GNU `ls` that's not found in other versions of `ls`.

Options include:

- Install the GNU fileutils package and run the `ls` command from it.
- Combine other tools to get similar results, such as `ls | grep -v '\.log$'`
- Use shell globbing patterns to get close, such as `ls *.[^g]` to list all files that don't end with the letter g.

Comment: I see bash in the prompt. Can also use extglob: `shopt -s extglob`; `ls !(*.log)`